# Is this valid way to prove $(-1)(-1) = 1$?

Tags: proof-verification

$(1-2)(1-2) =1-2-2+4=1$, using the distributive property. 
If it's not valid, why?

Comment: Sure, but it's  hard to imagine a situation in which you would  know $-2×-2=4$ without already having proved  $-1×-1=1$.

Comment: How do you know $(-2)(-2) = 4$?  I think you need to know $(-1)(-1) = 1$ to conclude this.

Comment: Hint for a correct proof.  Prove that $(-1)\cdot x = (-x)$  Prove then that $(-1)\cdot (-1)=-(-1)=1$ due to the uniqueness of inverses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not valid unless you have already proved that $(-2)(-2)=4$.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a variation though that does work.  Suppose we agree that $(-1)(-1)=x$, and we just don't know what $x$ is.  Then $$0=0\cdot 0=(1-1)\cdot(1-1)=1-1-1+(-1)(-1)=-1+x$$
So, $-1+x=0$, and thus the only thing $x$ can be is $1$.